# round number x-axis Jquery flot graph

Tags: jquery, graph, flot

I would like to round (0 decimals) the values on the x-axis of a flot graph. The x-axix show week numbers. Does anyone know how to do that?

http://www.snowcams.eu/snowcondition/saas%20fee/998

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is your solution (this can all be found in the plugin [API Documentation](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt))

```
$.plot(
    $("#placeholder"),
    [{data:d1, lines:{show: true}, points:{show: true}, label:"Mountain"}],
    {xaxis: {tickSize:1, tickDecimals:0 }}
);
```

Comment: You made my day